# iOS - UITableViewCell subviews on rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass with the init method:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [self.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        CGFloat xOffset = 10.0;
        CGFloat lineWidth = 1.0;
        UIView *footerLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset,
                                                                      self.frame.size.height - lineWidth,
                                                                      self.frame.size.width - xOffset,
                                                                      lineWidth)];
        [footerLine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [footerLine setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
        [self addSubview:footerLine];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So, I'm trying to draw a line at the bottom of the cell (offset a little in the x direcetion). This draws well upon the table loading, but I loose the footerLine view when I rotate the device to landscape and then back again.

I have a feeling this has something to do with the line:

```
[footerLine setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

but I've messed around with multiple combinations of the `UIViewAutoresizing` enums, and I can't get it to reappear after a rotation.

Is there something I could be missing with the `UIViewAutoresizing`??

Comment: You could try adding your `footerLine ` on `self.contentView`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggested you to add in cell.m file

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{ 

//there you should define your size for your line 
//footer line can be recognized by tag or define in cell it is up to you


}
```